# ¿Cómo poner argumentos y poder ejecutar run o debugg en spyder python?

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

He empezado a usar Spyder. Quiero ejecutar un script que tiene un nombre de fichero y un argumento. Si lo ejecuto desde consola ...

```
run fichero.py arg1
```

funciona.

Pero si quiero usar run -> configuration per line
entonces si lo pongo para ejecutar en un terminar externo, si se ejecuta. Pero si lo hago en Spyder da un error de BASESTRING

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

RESPUESTA TRAMPA:

Se me ocurrio usar otro .py donde ejecuto el fichero que me interesa con argumentos. Lo he llamado ejecutable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, así lo ejecuto.

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en que basestring solo lo soporta python 2,esto significa que tu interprete global es python 2,pero el interprete que usa spider es de python 3
en python 3 un string no es basestring, si no str (para un string como este `string = "hola"` el cual esta basado en unicode) o bytes (`bytestring = b"hola"`).
Si quieres sabe mas mira aqui : https://docs.python.org/es/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html
eso es para python 3.5,una version mas bien entigua,en versiones mas nuevas veras mas cambios importantes

Comment: como apendice te recomiendo el modulo `six` de python,el cual añade muchas utilidades que funcionan tanto en python 2 como en python 3,y que de python 2 a python 3 se cambian,por ejemplo,en python 2 para comprobar que `value` es un string haces `isinstance(value,basestring)`,pero algo que funciona tanto en python 2 como en 3 es `isinstance(value,six.string_types)`

Comment: nota six se instala con pip,(`pip install six`)

Comment: Temo no entenderte bien. Como ves , he puesto RESPUESTA CON TRAMPA en mi pregunta. Ejecutando mi fichero.py desde otro, ejecutable.py y llamando al primero con argumentos, se ejecuta. Pero.... continua sin irme el debug.  Y, esta no es la respuesta que me gusta. En eclipse, cuando he ejecutado JAVA, le puedes poner los argumentos que quieras y al hacer RUN o DEBUG, los usa sin problemas. Por ciero, uso un entorno creado desde anaconda y tiene python 3.8.11. Gracias

Comment: para ejecutar desde codigo de python otro archivo de python con argumentos,
depende de como estes ejecutando el script,si lo haces con `exec` es casi imposible,si lo haces con `os.system("archivo.py")` (os es una libreria) requeriria `os.system("archivo.py {ARGUMENTOS}")`,si lo haces con subproces (lo mas facil) seria `subprocess.run(["archivo.py",...])` donde `...` son tus argumentos

Comment: y si tu interprete global es python 3,es que estas aprendiendo python 2 y usando python 3,eso te dara problemas

Comment: perdon,con subprocess seria `subprocess.run(["python","fichero.py",...])`